# Laravel 5 shared object for the web app

Tags: object, laravel-5, shared

I'm new to laravel; i'd like to register an object variable with key "myObject", so that it can be acceded by all users using the current application, and can be acceded in any controller or view. the object can be changed (use a set method) whenever i want. i look for something like ServletContext in JEE or somthing like registry in Zend.
Thanks in advance for you detailed code

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the object into Laravel [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/container) as an instance for example, you may create your object instance using something like this:

```php
$object = new SomeClass(...);
App::instance('myObject', $myObject);
```

In this case, you can bind the object from a service provider. You can use the `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` which comes with `Laravel`. So, in this case, you may do something like this:

```php
// Import the dependencies using "use", omitted here
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function boot()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $object = new MyObjectClass();
        $this->app->instance('myObject', $object);

        // Share the instance globally in all views
        view()->share('myObject', $object);
    }
}
```

Later, you can use `$object = app('myObject')` to get the instance and if you would like to use it in views globally then you may use `view()->share('myObject', $object)` so you can access the object directly from any view usinf `$myObject` instance variable. There are other ways to bind an item into the container but this approach meets your need. Check the documentation for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your share. i can now get it from controller; how can i update the instance from an action? something like "set" new instance updated to the app object

Comment: Probably, just re-bind the instance into contaainer like I did into `Service Provider`. Check the [api](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Container/Container.html) reference for available methods.

Comment: i did it before, but there is no guide how to access the app container from the controller. any suggestion

Comment: i tried also this `$app=App::getInstance(); $app->instance('myObject', $updatedObj);` and in the use `use Illuminate\Container\Container as App;` , but seems the object is not updated!!

Comment: i went also with the singleton strategy, but no guide how to restore the new object. any help

Comment: Oops! I'll check soon if it's possible that way and let you know :-)